# Jquery animate changes in div height on ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-animate

I'm doing a simple ajax load to pull in search results and display them in a div:

```
$('#myDiv').load('update.php?id=123', function() {
   //callback here
});
```

This is all working fine and the div updates as expected.  'myDiv' either shrinks or grows depending on the number of results that are returned.

How can I animate the grow/shrink?

I know I can either slideUp/slideDown or show/hide e.g.

```
$('#myDiv').slideUp('fast').load('update.php?id=123', function() {
   $('#myDiv').slideDown('fast');
});
```

However, I dont want to shrink or hide it first - I want the height to go from its value before the ajax load to the value after the ajax load.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at jQuery elastic plugin, I think the way calculations are done in the background there would be a useful point of reference

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First you need to stop the auto-resize.

```
var $mydiv = $('#myDiv');
$mydiv.css('height', $mydiv.height() );
```

then once the load completes we wrap the contents in a div and use it to recalculate the height.

```
$mydiv.load('update.php?id=123', function() {
   $(this).wrapInner('<div/>');
   var newheight = $('div:first',this).height();
   $(this).animate( {height: newheight} );
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QVbYq/)**

Answer (score 0):

Give **#myDiv** a **style="position:relative;"**. Then in the callback from **.load()**, create a hidden , give it the width of **#myDiv** and load the results into it. Read the height of the hidden **div**, and do an animation to that height for **#myDiv**. delete the hidden **div**.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`jQuery.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). With it, you can animate any property to any value. In your case, you would animate the `height` from it's previous value to the new value.

Note, though, that you need to record the old value before replacing the content, as it's height (if not set absolute) will be updated when the contents are updated. Perhaps it could be beneficial to resize a wrapping container.

Like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>Content is here</div>
</div>
```

If you set the value of `overflow` to `hidden` for the `.wrapper`, you can then resize it to match the height of the inner `div` to achieve the effect you're after.